# Imported VMs don't start but load in infinite loop

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have imported an `ova` file into VirtualBox via `File -> Import Appliance`, but I only get the screen

[image]

and then the screen

[image]

The bar in the second screen runs twice till the end, then the frist screen appears and the whole loading process starts anew. On another machine the used `ova` worked fine. Why not here?

## Reading the log files

I powered the VM off, renamed the folder `Logs` to `Logs_old`, created a new folder `Logs`, turned the VM on, and `grep`ed "error", which had the output

```
00:00:00.537534 TM: GIP - CPU: iCpuSet=0x0 idCpu=0x0 idApic=0x0 iGipCpu=0x2 i64TSCDelta=0 enmState=3 u64CpuHz=2594107132(*) cErrors=0
00:00:00.537561 TM: GIP - CPU: iCpuSet=0x1 idCpu=0x1 idApic=0x1 iGipCpu=0x3 i64TSCDelta=0 enmState=3 u64CpuHz=2594106745(*) cErrors=0
00:00:00.537584 TM: GIP - CPU: iCpuSet=0x2 idCpu=0x2 idApic=0x2 iGipCpu=0x0 i64TSCDelta=0 enmState=3 u64CpuHz=2594106965(*) cErrors=0
00:00:00.537608 TM: GIP - CPU: iCpuSet=0x3 idCpu=0x3 idApic=0x3 iGipCpu=0x1 i64TSCDelta=0 enmState=3 u64CpuHz=2594102101(*) cErrors=0
00:00:13.878652 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005) aIID={7303a66d-433b-25a4-f9a8-fcadf87e0c2a} aComponent={DisplayWrap} aText={Could not take a screenshot (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:31.818238 /SELM/LoadHidSel/GstReadErrors          0 times
```

and "fail" which had the output

```
00:00:00.620956 AIOMgr: Flush failed with VERR_INVALID_PARAMETER, disabling async flushes
00:00:03.230756 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Boot from Floppy 0 failed
00:00:03.232068 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: CDROM boot failure code : 0003
00:00:03.232172 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Boot from CD-ROM failed
00:00:16.213370 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Boot from Floppy 0 failed
00:00:16.214449 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: CDROM boot failure code : 0003
00:00:16.214544 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Boot from CD-ROM failed
00:00:29.126271 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Boot from Floppy 0 failed
00:00:29.127556 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: CDROM boot failure code : 0003
00:00:29.127672 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Boot from CD-ROM failed
00:00:31.813714 /PDM/Queue/AHCI-Xmit/AllocFailures        0 times
00:00:31.813962 /PDM/Queue/DevHlp/AllocFailures         0 times
00:00:31.814256 /PDM/Queue/E1000-Rcv/AllocFailures        0 times
00:00:31.814600 /PDM/Queue/E1000-Xmit/AllocFailures        0 times
00:00:31.814785 /PDM/Queue/Keyboard/AllocFailures        0 times
00:00:31.814957 /PDM/Queue/Mouse/AllocFailures          0 times
00:00:31.815130 /PDM/Queue/Mouse_1/AllocFailures        0 times
```

I am not sure what to do with this.

Comment: Have you checked log files? Have you tried to import it again? Have yo checked for differences between both machines you have tried?

Comment: @Zina: The machines are both Kubuntu 14.4, but the hardware is different (unsurprisingly). I am not sure what I am looking for in the logs. I have the folder `Logs` with the files `VBox.log`, `VBox.log.1`, `VBox.log.2` and `VBox.log.3`. What should I look for in which file?

Comment: Search for "error", "fail", ... start the vm and when it reboots power off the vm and check the current log file. As the process did not complete, I would try to import it again. Check if there are any significant differences of VM hardware between the working and non-working copy. Are you importing the ova from the same source? Or are they two copies?

Comment: @Zina: Please see my update.

Comment: Those boot errors should be no problem, as you said it stats to boot and then falls back. I think you will have to look into the log files directly to try to find a reason when it restarts. What about the ova source? And would you care and retry the operation? And grep is by default case sensitive so if you did not use "-i" option you could have missed "Error"

Comment: @Zina: I added the infos with -i. Not sure how I should comply with your other requests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36857/discussion-between-zina-and-make42).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After troubleshooting it seemed like VT-X was not enabled (the OP was not able to change the number of CPUs for the VM and he has gotten the error message "VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED)" after doing a new import of the ova and trying to start the VM.

Enabling virtualization in BIOS

[image]

and reimporting the VM again did the trick.

For more information see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Intel_virtualization_.28VT-x.29

How to enable virtualisation for Lenovo see http://amiduos.com/support/knowledge-base/article/enabling-virtualization-in-lenovo-systems